# Is it permissible to take birth control pill?

Tags: birth-control

I asked this question before but didn’t get correct answer. Both me and my husband don't want kids right now. We both agreed not to have kids for first 2 year. So i decided to take birth control pill.  Is it permissible?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions twice and use meaningful tags. If you click on the correct tag you may already find answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is permissible to do so.
However, one must remember that if Allah wills to bring a soul into existence, no method, be it the use of contraception, be it the practice of coitus interrupts, nothing can stop a destined soul from coming into existence. For a reference in this regard, here is one: [Muslim 3371](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2008.%20Marriage/sahih-muslim-book-008-hadith-number-3371.html)